# Cordova version 6.4.0 - how to install httpd plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, nanohttpd

How do I add the plugin CorHttpd in my cordova project?
What is the command ?

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd  in this link, they says:

> **How to use CorHttpd:**
>
> Add the plugin to your cordova project:

I tried:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd.git
```

but this command is not working. After I run this command I got this message:

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd.gi t via git. Either
>   there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
>           Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessi ble on your PATH.

Need help about this matter.

Answer (score 1):

If repo name does not match with plugin id Cordova will try to serarch it via registry. Tested with Cordova 8.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all git sub-packages. Please run:

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

And then install your plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install git:

On windows: (git command have to be in your PATH environment variable)

[Download here](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

On linux / mac:

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```